# Visting daughter in Italy under tourist visa, do we have to provide detailed itinerary, booked tickets for travel inside Italy?

Tags: schengen, italy

I am from India and I got my visa appointment slot, but it is in the category of tourist visa, whereas I am going to be in Italy to stay with my daughter for a month. She is working there and has sent all the necessary documents. Do we still have to give a detailed itinerary?  To and fro flight tickets won't be sufficient to get the visa? We have not yet decided to visit other Schengen countries, it may be finalized after reaching these.

Comment: Your main itinerary is visiting your daughter.

Comment: If your daughter does not live in the specific city where your (international) flight arrives, showing how you will get from the airport to where she lives could be useful. Beyond that, probably not so much.